# CloudFront got X-Cache: Error from cloudfront with Status Code 200

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I was trying to host my site `example.com` using CloudFront with two S3 origins.`S3-main` for the site and `S3-resources` for the resources.

So I set `S3-main` as the `default(*)`. And `S3-resources` with path pattern `resources/*`.

When I go https://example.com I successfully loaded `index.html` under `S3-main`
But when I tried to GET `https://example.com/resorces/something.jpg` I got again `https://example.com/index.html` with header like below:

```
http GET https://example.com/resources/something.jpg

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1518
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 17 Aug 2017 03:29:52 GMT
ETag: "9776b731a6c42de14c929c10b4fec28c"
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Aug 2017 01:56:41 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
Via: 1.1 xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 3OVCtUAk8mGzKt2OJD5gX9KRLHG3CBSHXf-xxxxxxxx==
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
```

Why did I get `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and `X-Cache: Error from cloudfront` the same time? 
Why did I get `index.html` rather than `something.jpg` as I expected?

**Note**

I can get the image through `S3-resources.s3.amazonaws.com`

```
http GET https://S3-resources.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/something.jpg

Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 176182
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Thu, 17 Aug 2017 04:11:55 GMT
ETag: "xxxxxxx84b05fb6564323c"
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Aug 2017 02:59:12 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2: xxxx/xxxl+ijjM3YTxtQ4LpdHReEOhUvAz7uPFmVwzs8Foe4WOE=
x-amz-request-id: XXXX145CA3

+--------------------+
| NOTE: binary data  |
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your distribution settings... specifically, the Error Pages tab.

If you have configured custom error responses, it sounds like you have configured them incorrectly.   It is possible to substitute content *and* rewrite the HTTP status code when an error occurs, and the behavior you are reporting would be exactly consistent with such a (mis)configuration.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found the reason is that I've set the Error Pages to index.html. Meanwhile, miss configured the  `resources/*` to `S3-main`. So when `http GET https://example.com/resources/something.jpg` it should encounter a 404 error but was rewritten to 200 with an index.html return.

Comment: How'd you work around that? Or did you just decide that you didn't care?