# Facebook privacy policy URL: Bad Response Code: URL returned a bad HTTP response code (Using AWS S3 hosted Website)

Tags: facebook, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, privacy

I recently hosted a website on AWS S3 as a static page. For some unknown, Facebook won't allow me to submit the app using https://www.spotin.io/privacy-policy as an url because of a **bad response code**.

For now, I just added a simple generic privacy policy until I fix this, but I really need help. I read the other questions in Stack Over flow but their from 2 years ago and I following the given advice but it didn't work.

Here I include Facebook's debugger response image:
[Facebook Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DWFi.jpg)

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use CloudFront. Your page already delivers **404 code as a response**:

[image]
*via https://httpstatus.io/*

[image]
*via Postman*

Check your CloudFront setup, especially the Errors section. This alternative question might be of help:

[CloudFront got X-Cache: Error from cloudfront with Status Code 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726506/cloudfront-got-x-cache-error-from-cloudfront-with-status-code-200)